# Is there a Validation Rule that would allow the restriction of input values to be only of those that is present in another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are 3 tables in my Access database:

1. Product

- Primary Key: Prod_Code

2. Supplier

- Primary Key: Supp_Code

3. ProductSupplierPrice

- Foreign Keys: Prod_Code, Supp_Code

Essentially I created the third in order to map a product's price from a particular supplier, because a product's price differs per supplier.

I need to make a validation rule so that the values inputted for the foreign key attributes of the ProductSupplierPrice, are only the primary keys that already exist in Product and Supplier.

Is there a function that states a rule of something like IN(SELECT Prod_Code FROM Product)?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized while finally messing with my table that somehow it implicitly reinforced the validation I want, on its own.